# How to collect data usage information from the internet to iPhone with Xamarin / monotouch

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm needing to collect information from internet data usage on the iphone, the below code in C # I'm using only returns 0 values​​.

I'm using the right class?

have some reference I need to add in Xamarin?

appears in mono 3 types of classes, Coincidentally the "MacOsIPv4InterfaceStatistics" interface always returns the fixed value 0.

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.NetworkInformation/IPv4InterfaceStatistics.cs

```
Win32IPv4InterfaceStatistics
LinuxIPv4InterfaceStatistics
MacOsIPv4InterfaceStatistics


using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;


namespace Taximetro { public delegate void Update();

public static class ControleUso
{
    public static long controller;

    public static long BytesReceivedWiFi;
    public static long BytesSentWiFi;

    public static long BytesReceived3G;
    public static long BytesSent3G;

    public static Update UpdateMethod;

    public static void DoWork()
    {    
        foreach (var netint in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) {
            var stats = netint.GetIPv4Statistics ();

            //WiFi
            //if (netint.Name.StartsWith ("en")) {
                BytesReceivedWiFi += stats.BytesReceived;
                BytesSentWiFi += stats.BytesSent;
            //}

            //3G
            if (netint.Name.StartsWith ("pdp_ip")) {
                BytesReceived3G += stats.BytesReceived;
                BytesSent3G += stats.BytesSent;
            }
        }
        controller++;
        if (UpdateMethod != null) {
            UpdateMethod ();
        }
        Thread.Sleep (1000);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: AFAIK, iOS doesn't expose any public APIs to allow you to gather this data from a device.

Comment: This link shows a similar code written in ObjC
https://github.com/pkjmesra/DataUsage

but need to write in my project in C # - Xamarin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that data is uint and not long, which means it will overflow every 4GB of data.

Edit: After some Googling around I noticed that this data is reset on iOS reboot. Just some heads ups to anyone who might use this.

```
public enum InterfaceTypes
{
    Wifi,
    Cellular
}

public class DataUsage
{
    [DllImport ("libc")]
    static extern int getifaddrs (out IntPtr ifap);

    [DllImport ("libc")]
    static extern void freeifaddrs (IntPtr ifap);

    const int AF_LINK = 18;

    struct ifaddrs
    {
        public IntPtr ifa_next;
        public string ifa_name;
        public uint ifa_flags;
        public IntPtr ifa_addr;
        public IntPtr ifa_netmask;
        public IntPtr ifa_dstaddr;
        public IntPtr ifa_data;
    }

    public InterfaceTypes InterfaceType {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public uint BytesSent {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public uint BytesReceived {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public static List<DataUsage> GetAllNetworkInterfacesUsage ()
    {
        IntPtr ifap;
        if (getifaddrs (out ifap) != 0)
            throw new SystemException ("getifaddrs() failed");

        List<DataUsage> usages = new List<DataUsage> ();
        try {
            IntPtr next = ifap;
            while (next != IntPtr.Zero) {
                ifaddrs addr = (ifaddrs)Marshal.PtrToStructure (next, typeof(ifaddrs));
                next = addr.ifa_next;
                string name = addr.ifa_name;
                if (addr.ifa_addr != IntPtr.Zero) {
                    if (Marshal.ReadByte (addr.ifa_addr, 1) == AF_LINK) {
                        if (!name.StartsWith ("en") && !name.StartsWith ("pdp_ip"))
                            continue;
                        usages.Add (new DataUsage () {
                            InterfaceType = name.StartsWith ("en") ? InterfaceTypes.Wifi : InterfaceTypes.Cellular,
                            BytesReceived = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32 (addr.ifa_data, 40),
                            BytesSent = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32 (addr.ifa_data, 44)
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

        } finally {
            freeifaddrs (ifap);
        }
        return usages;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quero agradecer pela resposta.