# Measure network traffic at TCP level in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tcp, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Forms application, whose main target is iOS, that periodically makes some network calls.
I need to measure the total data transfer of the application and the total data transfer of a particular API call.

I'm using the ModernHttpClient as Http client and I can measure the Header and Content length of the request and response, but I'd like to do this at a TCP level and not at an HTTP level.

Is this possible? Can anyone help me?
I need this specifically for iOS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26312430/4984832